# Custom Iterator for Template

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am currently trying to build an iterator for a custom class and it's not going particularly well: The problem I'm having is that I my custom class uses a template and looks something like this:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
private:
    T memberVar;
};
```

Now, MyClass is basically a wrapper for memberVar which at the moment is a map or a map of maps. Now, I would like to create an iterator in another class and do useful things with it, i.e. access elements in my map or map of maps.

I have tried forwarding my iterator from my map, which doesn't give me an error in MyClass when I do something like `typedef T::iterator iterator;`, but it obviously doesn't want to be nice to me when I want to call `myIterator->first`, because now it doesn't believe me anymore that this will work. To be honest, I was surprised to see that my typedef actually works.

Now my question: Is there a nice way to do what I would like to do? Or have I manoeuvred myself into a corner here? Thanks very much in advance!

Simon

Some more information:

In a ClassA I instantiate a ClassB which then inherits MyClass with the right type T.
Then, in ClassA I also instantiate a ClassC which I give a reference to ClassB. Now, the error occurs, when I try to create `myIterator` in ClassC and try to do `myIterator->first`.

Comment: Don't you need `typedef typename T::iterator iterator`? I'm surprised that you say you don't get an error with `typedef T::iterator iterator`.

Comment: That does look better, you're right, but I didn't get an error. Would be nice if someone could explain why this is.

Also: For now, I have decided to simply use a `map <int, T>`, since then I can access the elements and at the moment, I only have maps. This is, I find, rather ugly though and I'd appreciate any better solution :)

Comment: He should get an error without the `typename`, but not all compilers enforce this yet.

Comment: How and where is `myIterator` defined?  That is the real question.

Comment: `myIterator` is defined like this: `ClassB::iterator myIterator;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, if your class template is always going to be a wrapper for
some instantiation of `map`, I'd repeat all of the `typedef`s in
`std::map` in your class, each time with:

```
typedef typename T::value_type;
// ...
```

(The `typename` is necessary, at least according to the standard, but 
version of g++, and compile all of your code with it, even if you use a
different compiler for the final builds.)

With regards to the `myIterator->first` not working, you'll have to tell
me where this line occured.  There should be no problem if it is in a
function in your class template, because the function shouldn't be
instantiated until it is used (and by that type, the type of `T` is
known).  If it is outside of the class template, it should still work,
provided you've declared the variable correctly, something like:

```
MyClass<std::map<T1, T2> >::iterator myIterator;
```

(Within the class template, just using `iterator` as the typename should
suffice, since the `typedef` is in scope.)

Comment: Okay, thanks very much! I added some more information in my first post.